# SQL INSERT denied error

Tags: php, sql

The following SQL query is causing an error:

```
INSERT INTO members.signIns
(employeeid, date, timeIn, timeOut, timeIn2, timeOut2, timeIn3, timeOut3, timeIn4, timeOut4)
 VALUES (1, 2012-08-10, 21-28, 21-28, 21-28, 21-28, 21-28, 21-28, 21-28, 21-28);
```

> Error: INSERT command denied to user 'waycov_scanlock'@'66.40.52.44'
>   for table 'signIns'

my hosting providor says its something to do with this code and not a settings issue

Comment: Make sure this user has permission to do inserts to the database. Verify with phpMyAdmin (I assume that's what you have to view your database through a GUI).

Comment: You're treating some strings like ints, add some quotes

Comment: @stevether That's part of the problem, but it's not what's preventing OP from `insert`ing.

Answer (score 5):

No, that's a permissions issues. If it was the multitude of syntax errors you have in there, you'd get a syntax error message instead.

You have no quotes around any of those values, so all those `-` are being seen as arithmetic substraction, so you're actually trying to insert

```
1, 1994, -7, -7, -7, -7, etc...
```

You query is syntactically fine, but without those quotes is logically invalid. It should be:

```
VALUES (1, '2012-08-10', '21-28', etc...)
```

Answer (score 1):

User `waycov_scanlock` does not have access to the table; plain and simple.

Have your hosting provider run this query for you:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,ADD,UPDATE,DELETE ON members.* TO waycov_scanlock@'66.40.52.44'
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD,UPDATE,DELETE ON waycov_scanlock.signIns TO 'waycov_scanlock'@'66.40.52.44'' at line 1

Comment: You will not be able to run the query yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you have not **INSERT** privilege for signIns table

make sure your database name is members.

also you  must have quotes around values like this 21-28

Comment: Try to read other answers before submitting the "same" answer (with poorer wording).